# One workout missing from phone

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

Yesterday I did two workouts using my Series 6 AW. One HIIT and one walk. Today, when I look at the fitness app on the phone, only one of the workouts is there, the HIIT. Is there any way to force the other to sync?

I’ve restarted both devices.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that as of today (Oct 23, 2020), this is a known bug.  Apple is aware of the issue but no GM fix has been issues yet.  It's been reported that un-pairing/re-pairing the AW doesn't resolve the issue.

There's a Watch and iPhone OS versions in beta right now, you can try installing one of those to see if it fixes the problem (installing beta OS's has its own risks so be sure you're aware of them before installing).

Otherwise, you'll have to wait until Apple puts the fix out for everyone.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Was hoping 14.1 may have fixed it but not so much.

Comment: I figured I'd chat with apple support about this.  They suggested un-pairing, re-paring the watch and restoring from backup, and then if it still happens, set the watch up as new.  It's not like there was much to re-setup so I did as they suggested.  I'm not hopeful that it'll fix anything

Comment: moving to latest iOS and it worked just fine